# How to read subshell output as each line is generated in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that looks like this:

```sh
name=""
while read i; do
    if [ -z "$name" ]; then
        name="$i"
    else
        echo "$i"
    fi
done < <(python tmp.py)
echo "$name"
```

where `tmp.py` is something like this:

```py
import time

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

but the problem is that the bash script waits for the python subshell to finish before it starts the while loop. Is there a way to read the subshell output as each line is generated? I need to be able to modify the outside script environment inside the loop (like the value of `name`), so the while loop can't be a subshell. I'm using bash 5.0.

Comment: It's not the bash script waiting for the output, it's the python buffering its output. Flush the buffer every time you need to process the output.

Comment: Oops, that's it. Thank you. `sys.stdout.flush()` for anyone else with the same problem. If you want to make an that an answer I can mark you correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the bash script waiting for the output, it's the python buffering its output. Flush the buffer every time you need to process the output.

You can do it through the modification of the python code via:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

or from the outside, telling the system to perform line buffering only (or no buffering at all):

```
stdbuf -oL python tmp.py
```

Comment: From the outside, `python -u` also forces it to be unbuffered